# Asp.Net: Passing value from Page to UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a textbox on my aspx page and I need a usercontrol to be able to see or access that value, how would I do that please.

I created a public property on my aspx page

```
public string txtBoolValue
    {
        get { return this.txtBool.Text;}
    }
```

How do I call that  from my ascx page?

Thanks

Melt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hai have a look at this http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/22-Passing-value-from-Page-to-UserControl-in-ASP-Net.aspx

Comment: That only works but only for static values set on the page, does anyone know if it's possible to do for dynamically generated values?

Comment: @ArminNehzat, I think you'll have to use the codebehind to do that.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of creating a property on page why don't you create a property on user control which can be set by the page. The code you mentioned in your question will create tight coupling between the page and user control.

Comment: ..and how would I do that guys?

Comment: create a public property on the control and refer to in your page code e.g. myControl.myProperty = "hello";

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
((Textbox)this.Parent.FindControl("YOUR TEXTBOX NAME IN ASPX PAGE")).Text
```